# setcookieの記述も、body内の画面要素の生成もPHPで達成する場合の設計方法とは？

Tags: php

PHPを初めて間もないものなのですが、setcookieの記載を
head以前で記述しなければならないことに関わり、疑問がわいてきてしまいました。

開発を進めているWebページは、送信ボタン押下でデータベースへのデータ登録が済むと
固有の伝票番号みたいなものを採取し、この番号を画面に表す仕様を考えています。

①データベースへの登録、及び採取した伝票番号を表示用にクッキーに保存するコーディングは
head内もしくはその前に記述予定です。

②当該画面は、データベースから動的に生成されるラジオボタンの羅列（INPUT TYPE=RADIO）、及び
リストボックス（SELECT要素）が構成される仕様です。

## ====質問====

①も②も同じデータベースなので、できたら１度の接続の機会で達成したいのですが
①のPHPをhead以前、②のPHPをbody内で記述する必要があるとなると、手段は
一括でHTMを吐くような設計になってくるのでしょうか？
（書きながら、ひょっとしてと思いましたが．．．配列のCOOKIEを格納して、body側で呼び出す？？）

毎回妙な質問をして本当に申し訳ありませんが、ご教示・ご見解を頂けましたら幸いです、何卒よろしくお願い申しあげます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBの接続ついては、１処理で接続を閉じなければ、最初にnewで接続した変数のインスタンスを使い回しで良いのではないかと思います。

setcookieについて、ブラウザに何らかの出力を行う前に実行する必要があります。詳しくはhttp://php.net/manual/ja/features.cookies.phpを見て下さい。

以下に、ブラウザに何らかの出力を行う前に setcookie()実行する例を２パターン書きます。（もう一つ出力制御関数を使う方法も有りますがここでは書きません。）

例１

```
<?php
$a1 = 'hello title';
$b1 = 'hello!!';
$c1 = 'ブロック要素';
$d=0;
for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
    $d1 += $i;
}

$tmp = <<<eot
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{$a1}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{$b1}</h1>
<div>{$c1}</div>
処理結果：{$d1}
</body>
</html>
eot;

setcookie('testcookie',$d1);

echo $tmp;
```

例２

```
<?php
$a1 = 'hello title';
$b1 = 'hello!!';
$c1 = 'ブロック要素';
$d=0;
for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
    $d1 += $i;
}

setcookie('testcookie',$d1);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?=$a1?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?=$b1?></h1>
<div><?=$c1?></div>
処理結果：<?=$d1?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 様　いつもご支援をありがとうございます。また分かりやすいご説明をありがとうございます。
例１はヒアドキュメントと呼ばれる技術ですね？？
参考書で拝見したことのある程度でどういった場面で有効なのか、分からなかったのですがこういう場面で有効なのですね。
こちらの例は、一つのPHPのくくりで、headもbodyも出力する例と解釈致しました。
（間違っていたらご指摘頂けますと幸いです））

例２は初めてみる技術で本当に驚きました。
<title><?=$a1?></title>、<h1><?=$b1?></h1>、<div><?=$c1?></div>と上段で【既に締めくくっているPHP】の
変数を参照できることに驚きました。PHPが「 ?> 」で括られていようと、同じページ内は当該変数のスコープ内ということ
なのでしょうかね？

Comment: phpは、スクリプトエラー以外で次のいずれかで終了します。１、スクリプトファイル（HTMLを含む）を最終行まで全て実行した時　２、exitを実行した時　
３、グローバルスコープでreturnを実行した時 http://php.net/manual/ja/tutorial.useful.php を読む事を、お勧めします。

Comment: @keitaro_so 様　いつもご支援ありがとうございます。URLを確認したところ、404エラーになってしまいました

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ja/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: yyz様・keitaro_so様
いつもご協力を頂きまして誠にありがとうございます、
yyz様にご紹介頂きましたURLの記事を確認後、先問い合わせで言及した①②のPHP（従来body内に一括コーディング）を、
head（①）とbody（②）に分割して記載しなおしました。
．．．ところが、
分割を思い立った目的：クッキーを所定の場所で格納する、がうまく作用していないのか、別の問題かで
状況を進展させることができませんでした。
SUBMITボタン押下後（データ登録後）のポストされた画面に、クッキーに格納された伝票番号が現れてこないのです。
F5キーでページを再更新すると、伝票番号は画面に現れてきます。

「ブラウザに何らかの出力を行う前に実行する必要があります。」が守られていても、
ポストされた画面に伝票番号を表示できない理由は、ひょっとして．．．
body側で読み込む段階で実はまだ格納されていない、ということでしょうか？

（コーディング順序的に、body構成前にsetcokieが実装されていようと、という意味。
一度のクライアント・サーバ間のやりとりが終わっていないと、
クッキーは格納されていない、ということでしょうか？セッションなら大丈夫かな？？）

Comment: phpでは、セットしたcookieは 次にページをロードするまで アクセスできないのですが、setcokieのvalueへ指定した変数を参照すれば良いのでは。
setcokieの注意すべき事はこのURLを見てください。 http://php.net/manual/ja/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-notes

Comment: 『phpではセットしたcookieは 次にページをロードするまで アクセスできない』←そうなんですね、やはりそうでしたか。ご提案の方式もしくはセッションの利用も含めて、少し解決策を模索
してみます。ありがとうございました。